# If/for loop issues

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm making a variant of battleship, and I'm trying to make it so that each butto, when pressed, will turn green if it is a hit or red if it is a miss. The coordinates of the ship are read from a random line of an imported text file and stored into numbers[] when the main program starts. I can get the buttons to work for the first integer of the array, but the for loop doesn't seem to be finishing. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class Buttons extends JPanel 
{
 JButton[] btn; 
 static int[] numbers = new int[5];

  public Buttons() throws IOException
 {
String[] numberLine = choose(new File("Coords.txt")).split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberLine[i]);
        }

String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
btn = new JButton[25];

setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

setBackground(Color.blue);
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
    btn[i] = new JButton(letters.charAt(i) + Integer.toString(i));



ButtonListener blisten = new ButtonListener();

  for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
  {
  btn[i].addActionListener(blisten);

  }



  for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
  {
  add (btn[i]);
  }


} //Ends Constructor

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
 {


public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
  Object source = event.getSource();

  for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
   for(int u=0;u<5;u++) //This is where the issue seems to be.
    if(source==btn[i])  //It only does the for loop for u=0 (I think).
      if(i==numbers[u]) //Because only one button comes out as a hit.
  {
    btn[i].setBackground(Color.green);
    btn[i].setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
    btn[i].setBackground(Color.red);
    btn[i].setEnabled(false);

    }



    }
}



public static String choose(File f) throws FileNotFoundException
{
 String result = null;
 Random rand = new Random();
 int n = 0;
 for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(f); sc.hasNext(); )
 {
    ++n;
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if(rand.nextInt(n) == 0)
       result = line;         
 }

 return result;      
}

} //Ends Program
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isolate the problem. Try to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: I fixed the issue by deleting the for loop and changed the if loop to be if(i==numbers[0] || i==numbers[1] || i==numbers[2] || i==numbers[3] || i==numbers[4]), but I would still appreciate some help or insight into why the original code did not work. I isolated the problem to be the second for loop in the original chain of loops.

Comment: Why do you have 3 different `for(int i = 0; i<25; i++)`? Just a single loop should be enough.

Comment: @dic19 in reference to the earlier loops where I was creating the buttons and adding them? I was following a guide set out by my instructor, and I think they were just trying to break apart the code as much as possible to make sure we could understand it.

Comment: @SameerSawla The text file was broken apart into lines that each consisted of 5 integers, which were the coordinates of the ships on the 1-D array of buttons. That part of the code parses the randomly selected line of the imported text file so that it can store just the integers of the line into the array.

Comment: @user3046635 noted! If that is the goal then it's ok I guess. But keep in mind you can optimize that part :)

Comment: @user3046635 Are you trying to create a 26x26 grid?